# Change values in column based on condition- Python

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataset containing a thousand zeros, five hundred ones, and so on.
I want to change the first 400 zeros to 0.3, the next 600 zeros to 0.6.
Then, I want to change the first 200 ones to 1.4, the next 300 ones to 1.8.
And so on.

The whole point being I want to change the integer value to some fractions based on the frequency specified.

Ex: Dataset: 0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1
Output: 0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.8,1.2,1.2,1.2,1.4,1.4,1.4
Input: Frequency, Dataset
Frequency=[4,1] for 0 & [3,3] for 1
New dataset=[0.2,0.8] for 0 & [1.2,1.4] for 1

Comment: Will the data points always be sorted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your datapoints are sorted, a simple solution would be

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1]})

frequencies = [
    [4, 1],
    [3, 3],
]

new_values = [
    [0.2, 0.8],
    [1.2, 1.4],
]

a = np.concatenate(frequencies)
df['new_col'] = np.concatenate(new_values)[np.arange(len(a)).repeat(a)]
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    col  new_col
0     0      0.2
1     0      0.2
2     0      0.2
3     0      0.2
4     0      0.8
5     1      1.2
6     1      1.2
7     1      1.2
8     1      1.4
9     1      1.4
10    1      1.4
```

Comment: What is a? Or should it be frequencies? Returns "object too deep for desired array"

Comment: My apologies! Answer updated.